# How to use the Programmable Interrupt Controller PIC and Programmable Interval Timer PIT to schedule processes on a kernel?

Tags: timer, x86, operating-system, osdev

In my "wannabe-kernel" I've successfully enable software interrupt handling via IDT in protected mode. Now I am moving to hardware interrupts to be able to assign time slice to processes. The problem is that my kernel do not receive any interrupt for PIT.

```
inline void outb(uint8_t port,unsigned char value)
    {
       __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %%ax,%%dx": :"d" (port), "a" (value));
    }

    static inline uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
    {
        uint8_t ret;
        __asm__ __volatile__ ( "inb %1, %0" : "=a"(ret) : "d"(port) );
        return ret;
    }

    #define PIC1    0x20
    #define PIC2  0xA0   
    #define PIC1_COMMAND    PIC1
    #define PIC1_DATA       (PIC1+1)
    #define PIC2_COMMAND    PIC2
    #define PIC2_DATA       (PIC2+1)

    #define ICW1_ICW4       0x01        
    #define ICW1_SINGLE     0x02        
    #define ICW1_INTERVAL4  0x04        
    #define ICW1_LEVEL      0x08        
    #define ICW1_INIT       0x10        

    #define ICW4_8086       0x01    
    #define ICW4_AUTO       0x02        
    #define ICW4_BUF_SLAVE  0x08
    #define ICW4_BUF_MASTER 0x0C    
    #define ICW4_SFNM       0x10

    void init_pic()
    {
        unsigned char a1, a2;
        unsigned offset_master = 0x20;
        unsigned offset_slave = 0x28;
        a1 = inb(PIC1_DATA);                        
        a2 = inb(PIC2_DATA);

        outb(PIC1_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT+ICW1_ICW4);  
        outb(PIC2_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT+ICW1_ICW4);
        outb(PIC1_DATA, offset_master);                 
        outb(PIC2_DATA, offset_slave);                 
        outb(PIC1_DATA, 4);                      
        outb(PIC2_DATA, 2);                       
        outb(PIC1_DATA, ICW4_8086);
        outb(PIC2_DATA, ICW4_8086);
        outb(PIC1_DATA, a1); 
        outb(PIC2_DATA, a2);
    }

    #define PIT_COMMAND 0x43
    #define PIT_DATA1   0x40
    #define PIT_DATA2   0x41
    #define PIT_DATA3   0x42

    void init_pit()
    {
       uint32_t divisor = 1193180 / 50;

       outb(PIT_COMMAND, 0x36);

       uint8_t l = (uint8_t)(divisor & 0xFF);
       uint8_t h = (uint8_t)( (divisor>>8) & 0xFF );

       outb(PIT_DATA1, l);
       outb(PIT_DATA1, h);  
    }
```

And the timer handler

```
    unsigned tick = 0;
    void timerHandler()
    {
       tick++;
       char* ascii_code;
       itoa(ascii_code, 'd', tick);
       terminal_writestring("PIT Tick: ", &terminal);
       terminal_writestring(ascii_code, &terminal);
       terminal_writestring("\n", &terminal);
    }
```

The bochs provide not much details about cause of isse:

```
00122970752e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg       (vector=0x20)
00122970752e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x0d)
00122970752e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x08)
```

I've registered to IDT timer handler same way (only entry number is different) as software interrupt handler.

EDIT: IDT setup code as requested:

```
    struct __InteruptDescriptorTableEntry
    {
       uint16_t offset_low;
       uint16_t selector; 
       uint8_t zero;      
       uint8_t type_attr; 
       uint16_t offset_up; 
    } __attribute__((packed));
    typedef struct __InteruptDescriptorTableEntry IDTEntry;

    struct _ITD_PTR
    {
        uint16_t idtSize;
        uint32_t idtBaseAddr;
    } __attribute__((packed));
    typedef struct _ITD_PTR _IDT_PTR;

    void zeroIDT()
    {   
        unsigned i;
        for(i=0;i<NUM_IDT_ENTRIES-1;++i)
        {
            IDTEntry nullIDTEntry = fillIDTEntry(0,0,0);
            registerInterupt(nullIDTEntry, i);
        }
    }

    void registerInterupt(const IDTEntry entry, const unsigned intNo)
    {
        if(intNo < NUM_IDT_ENTRIES)
            InteruptDescriptorTable[intNo] = entry;
    }

    #define LOW_FUN_ADDR(fun) ( (uint32_t)fun & 0xFFFF )
    #define UP_FUN_ADDR(fun) ( (uint32_t)fun >> 16) & 0xFFFF

    IDTEntry fillIDTEntry(uint32_t intHandler,
                          uint16_t selector,   
                          uint8_t type_attr)

    {   IDTEntry newEntry;
        newEntry.offset_low = LOW_FUN_ADDR(intHandler); 
        newEntry.selector = selector; 
        newEntry.zero = 0;     
        newEntry.type_attr = type_attr;
        newEntry.offset_up = UP_FUN_ADDR(intHandler);
        return newEntry;
    }

    extern void _lidt(_IDT_PTR* idtPtr);
    void timerHandler_TEST();

    void loadIDT()
    {
        zeroIDT();
        _IDT_PTR idtPtr;
        idtPtr.idtSize = sizeof(struct __InteruptDescriptorTableEntry)*256 - 1;
        idtPtr.idtBaseAddr = (uint32_t) &InteruptDescriptorTable;

        IDTEntry printOnScreenInt = fillIDTEntry((uint32_t)interupt_pritnOnScreen, 0x18, 0xee);
        registerInterupt(printOnScreenInt, 50);

        IDTEntry timerIntEntry = fillIDTEntry((uint32_t)timerHandler_TEST, 0x18, 0xee);
        registerInterupt(printOnScreenInt, 13);
        _lidt(&idtPtr);
    }
```

Assembly source:

```
.global _lidt
_lidt:
    push %ebp
    mov %esp,%ebp
    mov 8(%esp), %eax
    lidt (%eax)
leave
ret
```

EDIT2: I've changed masks of PIT to:

```
a1 = 0x7F; //master                        
a2 = 0xFF; //slave
```

to receive only PIT int, but IRQ is not delivered (no triple fault).

 EDIT3: `info gdt` and `info IDT` :

```
IDT[0x20]=32-Bit Interrupt Gate target=0x0018:0x001009c0, DPL=3
IDT[0x32]=32-Bit Interrupt Gate target=0x0018:0x001009c0, DPL=3

GDT:
GDT[0x00]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0x00000000
GDT[0x01]=Code segment, base=0x00000000, limit=0xffffffff, Execute/Read, Non-Conforming, Accessed, 32-bit
GDT[0x02]=Data segment, base=0x00000000, limit=0xffffffff, Read/Write, Accessed
GDT[0x03]=Code segment, base=0x00000000, limit=0xffffffff, Execute/Read, Non-Conforming, Accessed, 32-bit
GDT[0x04]=Data segment, base=0x00000000, limit=0xffffffff, Read/Write, Accessed
GDT[0x05]=32-Bit TSS (Busy) at 0x00101000, length 0x00068
```

Comment: We're going to need you IDT setup code instead of all of this, as this is not related to the error you've got.

Comment: @user35443 Code posted

Comment: A side note - you probably want `0x8e`, not `0xee` for interrupt gates - otherwise *the userspace will be able to invoke those handlers* with `int` instruction.

Comment: Please show us the outputs of `info gdt` and `info idt` Bochs gives you.

Comment: Did you remap the IRQs? By default, IRQ0-7 is mapped to 8-15, which conflicts with the interrupts in protected mode (in particular, IRQ 0 conflicts with double fault exception).

Comment: @Luaan: yes, he did; notice that the interrupt triggering faults is on vector 0x20.

Comment: @Griwes Hmm, yeah. So the question is, is IRQ 0 now really on 13?

Comment: @Luaan: IRQ0 is 0x20. 0x0D (so 13) is a #GP.

Comment: @Griwes Maybe I'm missing something really stupid... but why is he mapping the timer handler to 13, then?

Comment: @Luaan: good catch, although it kind of looks like a typo (especially when looking at `info idt` output).

Comment: @Griwes Yeah, the `info idt` is useful. Now I'm just thinking, isn't he selecting the 0x06 selector instead of 0x01 or some such? My x86 is a bit rusty, but the lowest two bits are "skipped", resulting in 110 == 0x06 - I don't see that in the GDT. What happens if you use `0x08` instead of `0x18`?

Comment: @Luaan: the selector is correct. Its value is `0x11000`, but the lowest two bits aren't *skipped*, they are *masked out*. The values for selector are multiples of 8, so 0x8, 0x10, 0x18, 0x20, 0x28 and so on.

Comment: @Griwes Oh, duh. It's three bits, not two. I forgot the GDT/LDT bit. So he is actually selecting segment `0x03`, which should be fine. Chm. I don't really see anything suspicious in the code (maybe apart from the fact that both IDT entries point to the same memory, but I assume that's some global handler).

Comment: Just to say, you send the EOI to PICs right? There may be a lot of reasons to not receive IRQs, mostly hardware reasons. You need to do some unit testing. Just add features step by step. For example, since the PIT is already configured and is already firing IRQs, comment the code to reprogram it. Also comment out the code to remap the IRQs base and check if your int 08h handler is executed. Reintroduce the code commented out one functional block at time until you no longer receive the IRQ 0.

Comment: @knm241 Yes, that was one of many issues ( lack of EOI). Now I am dealing with, let's say main cause. Just to be sure, using interrupt handler in C is not something bad, right? I mean what about `iret` in C int hanlder

Comment: iret is not ret, you have to use inline assembly. C is fine as long as you remember where to use assembly

Comment: my advice is still the same: do unit testing. 1. Clear IF with cli. 2. Switch to protected mode 3. Set the whole IDT with the same trivial handler (just iret). 4. Test IDT with int xx instructions. 5. Make the IRQ0 handler print something (simple and each time different) and set IF with sti. 6. Reprogram the PICs. 7. Reprogram the PIT. 8. Write IRQ0 handler.  Move to following step only when the previous one is working. This way you can tell what make things stop working

Comment: Minimal working PIT + PIC example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/1e87cda4c02d7c94e08053c05c4b4a49c649473c/pit_protected.S